# Google Maps API - Nearby Location Search

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm having a tough time with the Google Maps API. What I'm looking to do is have the google maps lookup my location on page load, then show a list of "X" where X is type of restaurant. So for example the X would be pre populated with Pizza, so on page load the browser would lookup the location then automatically show a list of Pizza places nearby on the map.

Comment: Is there a question?  Or is this a specification for someone to write code for you?

Comment: Something like [this](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_10minuteDriveG.html?address=Manhattan,%20NY&q=Pizza)?

Comment: Thank you geocode so much for your help!

Comment: @geocodezip how did you get google api to return 20 results?

Comment: Asked for something that had more than 20 results in that area (I'm not sure what your issue is, but it is probably a different question, shouldn't be asked in the comments)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the `textSearch` method in the Places Library, details below:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#TextSearchRequests

This lets you return results for a text query e.g., "pizza", within a certain area.